# How to remove redundancy from and add flexibility to template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction, type-deduction

I want to use `constexpr`, compile time generated `std::arrays` for fast value-lookup instead of lengthy runtime calculations. For that I drafted a templated `constexpr`function that will be executed at compile time.

Please see the following example code, which allows for ultrafast access to Triangle and Fibonacci numbers and factorials.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

constexpr size_t ArraySize = 20u;

// Some generator functions -------------------------------------------------------------
constexpr size_t getTriangleNumber(size_t row) noexcept {
    size_t sum{};
    for (size_t i{ 1u }; i <= row; i++) sum += i;
    return sum;
}
constexpr unsigned long long getFibonacciNumber(size_t index) noexcept {
    unsigned long long f1{ 0ull }, f2{ 1ull }, f3{};
    while (index--) { f3 = f2 + f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3; }
    return f2;
}
constexpr unsigned long long getFactorial(size_t index) noexcept {
    unsigned long long result{ 1 }; 
    while (index > 0) { result *= index; --index; }
    return result;
}

// Generate a std::array with n elements of a given type and a generator function -------
template <typename DataType, DataType(*generator)(size_t), size_t... ManyIndices>
constexpr auto generateArray(std::integer_sequence<size_t, ManyIndices...>) noexcept {
    return std::array<DataType, sizeof...(ManyIndices)>{ { generator(ManyIndices)... } };
}

// The arrays ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
constexpr auto TriangleNumber = generateArray<size_t, getTriangleNumber>(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, ArraySize>());
constexpr auto FibonacciNumber = generateArray<unsigned long long, getFibonacciNumber>(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, ArraySize>());
constexpr auto Factorial = generateArray<unsigned long long, getFactorial>(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, ArraySize>());

// Some debug test driver code
int main() {
    for (const auto t : TriangleNumber) std::cout << t << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
    for (const auto f : FibonacciNumber) std::cout << f << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
    for (const auto f : Factorial) std::cout << f << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see. The template uses a parameter "DataType". In my opinion this is redundant. This is always the return type of the generator function. And it will also determine the data type for the `std::array`

So, how can we eliminate this redundancy and just use the type given by the generator function?

Additionally. The functions parameter is always `size_t`. There is also a redundancy and it is also not very flexible. The type of "ManyIndices" and the function parameter are always the same. So, no need to write that double.

Regarding flexibility. If I want to use a generator function with a different parameter data type, say, `unsigned long long` as in

```
constexpr unsigned long long factorial(unsigned long long n) noexcept {
    return n == 0ull ? 1ull : n * factorial(n - 1ull);
}
```

I cannot do that. So, basically everything should be deduced from the generators functions signature.

This is also valid for the lines like

```
constexpr auto Factorial = generateArray<unsigned long long, getFactorial>(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, ArraySize>());
```

Here, `size_t` is also the type of the parameter of the given function.

---

**So, how eliminate redundancy and add flexibility?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataType` can be deduced from passed generator, use `std::declval`.

`std::integer_sequence` can be replaced by `std::index_sequence`.

Size for calculation must be provided explicitly.

```
template <typename GEN, size_t ... Indices>
constexpr auto generateArray2Helper(GEN gen, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    return std::array<decltype(std::declval<GEN>()(size_t{})), sizeof...(Indices)>{ gen(Indices)... };
}

template <size_t N, typename GEN>
constexpr auto generateArray2(GEN gen) {
    return  generateArray2Helper(gen, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

// The arrays ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
constexpr auto TriangleNumber = generateArray2<ArraySize>(getTriangleNumber);
constexpr auto FibonacciNumber = generateArray2<ArraySize>(getFibonacciNumber);
constexpr auto Factorial = generateArray2<ArraySize>(getFactorial);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9xoP5b)

Comment: That is exactly what I need. Reading about ````std::declval```` in cppreference does not explain too much to me. I need to read further. Thanks. +1+accept.

Comment: `std::declval<GEN>()` declval is "fake-function" which returns `GEN&&`, so it is treated as  temporary object of GEN type, then we call `()` operator for this object with argument 0 as  type of `size_t` - by this we can access return type of `GEN{}(argument)` invocation - `decltype( invocation of GEN with 0 as argument )`.

Comment: you need a decay on gen's return value.

Answer (score 1):

[c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) version:

```
template<std::size_t...Is>
constexpr auto index_over(auto f, std::index_sequence<Is...>){
  return f(std::integral_constant<std::size_t,Is>{}...);
}
template<auto N>
constexpr auto index_upto(auto f){
  return index_over(f, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

template<auto size>
constexpr auto gen_array(auto f){
  return index_upto<size>([&](auto...Is){
    return std::array{f(Is)...};
  });
}
```

Comment: Also very good. But, I am still at C++17. Unfortunately . . .